# Dynamic default GRUB startup

Tags: grub2

Some backstory:

I am dual-booting Linux and Windows.  I use Linux for my hobby programming and Windows for games (I can do the same work on either).  Sometimes, I tend to be more interested in programming than I am in playing games.  As a result, there will be weeks that I don't boot into Windows at all, and other weeks that I don't boot into Linux.  Linux is my default boot option for GRUB, so the weeks that I'm playing games, I get tempted to set Windows to default.  But then, I think "Well, what about the weeks that I don't use Windows?".

My question:

Is it possible to set a dynamic default boot option for GRUB?  For example, GRUB could count the times I've booted into Windows and come up with something like "This person has logged into Windows five times in a row, and therefor I will change the default boot option to Windows".  Likewise, when I get in the mood to program, GRUB would figure out that I want Linux to be default.

Thanks.